# Avoiding status bar while using Papyrus app

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, notes

I use Papyrus app to take notes. One big problem I encounter is that my hand occasionally touches the bottom right corner of the screen, prompting the device to open the menu there.

This hinders my writing process and spoils my handwriting. Is there a way to disable or hide the status bar?

Comment: Would hiding the system bar really solve the problem, or would it just mean you end up with little marks in the bottom-right corner of your notes, because your hand still touches the screen there? (I'm not a Papyrus user, so I don't know how it uses the screen.)

Comment: Switch on Immersive mode ! It will make it full screen and remove all the bars :)
I am guessing you are talking about the system notification bar ?

Comment: @DanHulme: Papyrus detects only stylus; so no marks will enter the note. The problem is I need to close the menu every time it springs up.

Comment: @AadiDroid: Is it there in JellyBean? I googled and I seem to find it is available only if offered by the app.